# Changing direction on click in Endless scroll div

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've been trying to customize [jQuery Endless Div Scroll v1.0](http://www.codicode.com/demo/endless_scroll/)

The scroll bit works but I have added two buttons with ids left and right to change the direction of the scroll which don't work. Here is my code:

```js
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#s1").endlessScroll({ 
  width: '100%', 
  height: '100px', 
  steps: -2, speed: 40, 
  mousestop: true });
  
 $("#left").click(function() {
  $("#s1").endlessScroll({ 
  width: '100%', 
  height: '100px', 
  steps: 2, speed: 40, 
  mousestop: false });
   
  });
 $("#right").click(function() {
   $("#s1").endlessScroll({ 
   width: '100%', 
  height: '100px', 
  steps: -2, speed: 40, 
  mousestop: false });
   
  });
    });
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can get this to work?

Comment: You reinitialize `endlessScroll` on every click - I doubt it is good decision. Have you tried to change `steps` (to `-2` or `2` either via plugin API or directly internal variable in plugin) on `#left` and `#right` clicks?

Comment: Actually reinitializing freezes the div entirely, but the code seemed correct. I'm not sure how to change steps via the plugin API or directly internal variable.

Comment: Download plugin and change its source code as you need. You can, for example, improve plugin by checking on creation whether element is already initialized or not. And if is already initialized, then just change its options. This plugin is quite small, so there should be no problems with its changing.

Comment: The element is being initialized already in the plugin. I'm going to try and make it work through the options that are already there  I have a feeling I may have to look for a completely different script that scrolls as well as provides a way to change direction of the scroll. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Ok so I almost have a solution. I had to use a completely different script but this was basically what I needed http://jsfiddle.net/CQNTy/29/. Except, when I click on "Right" the left most part comes empty. Any idea what I need to change here? I have tried a lot of things and am at my wits end here. Any help would be great.

Comment: You forgot to add elements to left when they go out of right border. Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQNTy/30/). Maybe I miscalculate a little bit with borders, but the idea is in written `else if ()`